# Error: [vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "react-redux"

Tags: reactjs, redux, vite

I was trying to build small vite project and I encountered this problem during building .

```
This is most likely unintended because it can break your application at runtime.
If you do want to externalize this module explicitly add it to
`build.rollupOptions.external`
error during build:
Error: [vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "react-redux" from "C:/Users/user/OneDrive/Documents/react course work/fast-react-pizza/src/main.jsx".
This is most likely unintended because it can break your application at runtime.
If you do want to externalize this module explicitly add it to
`build.rollupOptions.external`
    at viteWarn (file:///C:/Users/user/OneDrive/Documents/react%20course%20work/fast-react-pizza/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-df561101.js:48142:27)
    at onwarn (file:///C:/Users/user/OneDrive/Documents/react%20course%20work/fast-react-pizza/node_modules/@vitejs/plugin-react/dist/index.mjs:238:9)
    at onRollupWarning (file:///C:/Users/user/OneDrive/Documents/react%20course%20work/fast-react-pizza/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-df561101.js:48171:9)
    at onwarn (file:///C:/Users/user/OneDrive/Documents/react%20course%20work/fast-react-pizza/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-df561101.js:47902:13)
    at file:///C:/Users/user/OneDrive/Documents/react%20course%20work/fast-react-pizza/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:24152:13
    at Object.logger [as onLog] (file:///C:/Users/user/OneDrive/Documents/react%20course%20work/fast-react-pizza/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:25825:9)
    at ModuleLoader.handleInvalidResolvedId (file:///C:/Users/user/OneDrive/Documents/react%20course%20work/fast-react-pizza/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:24738:26)
    at file:///C:/Users/user/OneDrive/Documents/react%20course%20work/fast-react-pizza/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:24698:26
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

I tried requiring instead of importing but it failed too.

Answer (score 0):

add dependecie redux to package.json

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).